# MySQL Left Join with Right Field Null Check

Tags: mysql

I couldn't able to solve the following using LEFT JOIN with ON condition of Left Table colC = Right Table colBB AND Right Table colAA IS NOT NULL.

## Left Table

```
colA       colB       colC
----       ----       -----
a           1         x
b           2         y
c           3         z
```

## Right Table

```
colAA      colBB
----       -----
NULL       y
```

My target achievement (below) is to have all records on the Left Table that colC matches Right Table colBB with condition on Right Table colAA is not null.

## Result

```
colA     colB    colC
----     ----    ----
a         1      x
c         3      z
```

How do I achieve this in MySQL statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Edited the question to handle single NULL record

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

```
select l.colA,
l.colB,
l.colC
from leftTbl l
join rightTbl r
on l.colC = r.colBB
where r.colAA is not null;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49143/1)

Comment: sorry but the statement returns empty records. my expectation is stated on the Result above. thanks anyway.

Comment: Empty records?? Please check the fiddle link in my answer.

Comment: OK i know why it's empty. Let's say if my Right Table only have one record of by reference above of row NULL and 'y'?